# Continue fitting an sklearn imputer that did not converge after max_iter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bayesian, imputation

I fit an `sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer` using default settings (a `BayesianRidge()` regressor), and after 200 iterations of fitting the regressor still hadn't converged to within the scaled tolerance, though the reported change was still decreasing. Since I had maxed out the iterations (which in my case took ~13 hours), I saved the "fitted" imputer using `joblib`.

What I'd like to do is continue training the regressor do get a better imputation of my missing values, but when I load the imputer and call `fit()` on the same data, it seems to start all over, i.e. (I assume) not using the previously optimized regularization parameters.

Is it possible to resume imputer estimator training using `IterativeImputer`, or is there perhaps another way to do this?

An example script:

```py
import numpy as np
from joblib import dump, load
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

data = np.random.normal(size=(10000, 100))

# Setting max_iter to be low so it doesn't converge in time
imputer = IterativeImputer(max_iter=5, random_state=42, verbose=2)
imputer.fit(data)
dump(imputer, "imputer.joblib")

# Assuming the imputer does not converge to within the default tolerance (1e-3)
imputer = load("imputer.joblib")
imputer.fit(data)  # Wishfully thinking the imputer will simply continue improving
```

On a small side-note, is there any way to get a sense of the training error when fitting a Bayesian Ridge regressor using `IterativeImputer`? `verbose=2` simply outputs a "change" value, which doesn't give a very clear picture of how the regressor is actually performing, but maybe I don't understand the estimator well enough.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question, it's worth pointing out that convergence for the IterativeImputer is still an open problem -- it frequently never converges ([see GitHub issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14338)). So, it's a question whether continued training would eventually lead to convergence at all.